# How to unit test a method that is working on soap request XML

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test case using Microsoft test tools for a method that is accessing soap request XML from soap body. Following is the code of the method for what I'm trying to unit test:

```
public static string GetSoapXmlRequest()
        {
            XmlDocument xmlSoapRequest = new XmlDocument();
            string strFormatedXML = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Logger.Info("-----------Starting of GetSoapXmlRequest method Call-------");
                Logger.Info(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ToString());
                using (Stream receiveStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
                {
                    if (receiveStream.Position > 0)
                    {
                        receiveStream.Position = 0;
                    }
                    using (StreamReader readStream =
                    new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {
                        xmlSoapRequest.Load(readStream);
                    }
                }
                Logger.Info(AsString(xmlSoapRequest));
                if (xmlSoapRequest.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    XDocument xmlInputSoapRequest = XDocument.Parse(xmlSoapRequest.OuterXml);
                    XElement soapAuthToken = xmlInputSoapRequest.Root.Elements().FirstOrDefault();
                    XElement soapBody = xmlInputSoapRequest.Root.Elements().LastOrDefault();
                    XmlReader readerSoapAuthToken = soapAuthToken.CreateReader();
                    var xmlSoapAuthToken = XDocument.Load(readerSoapAuthToken);
                    XmlReader readerSoapBody = soapBody.CreateReader();
                    var xmlSoapBody = XDocument.Load(readerSoapBody);
                    xmlSoapAuthToken.Root.Add(xmlSoapBody.Root.Elements());
                    strFormatedXML = xmlSoapAuthToken.ToString();
                }
                Logger.Info(strFormatedXML);
                Logger.Info("-----------End of GetSoapXmlRequest method Call-------");
                return strFormatedXML;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Below is the test method that I'm trying to write for above method:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetSoapXmlRequest_PostUCCValidationResult_ReturnsTrue()
        {
            var req = new HttpRequest("", "http://tempuri.org", "");
            HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(req, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
            string soapRequest = Utility.GetSoapXmlRequest();
            Assert.AreEqual(true, string.IsNullOrEmpty(soapRequest));
        }
```

please suggest how to mock the request xml and how to unit test the same method.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @PeterCsala I've already stated my problem clearly as "how to mock/setup the SOAP request xml"